# SFTP with MySQL user pass instead of PAM

Tags: ssh, users, mysql, pam, sftp

Is there a way for people to log onto a Debian server via sftp using just MySQL database table as authentication, not by adding a user to the system?

I know it can be done over ftp and TLS but I really don't want to use that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cent suggestion: you could use [PAM](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/) to do this.

E.g. Use some pam module as [pam-mysql](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net) to store some of your users in mysql and [pam_require](http://www.splitbrain.org/projects/pam_require) to avoid that mysql-stored users can access other than sftp service.

Start looking here: [Modules/Applications available or in progress...](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/modules.html)

Comment: thats is a very useful link thanks very much, Ill mark this answered as its what im looking for. Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to have a UID assigned to each user in this case?  i.e. you're adding users anyway; it's just that the UID/password/etc. for some of them are stored in MySQL.  I suppose you could use a single UID for all of them, but then they could read and overwrite each other's files.

Comment: @Jander, if users own files in the file system, they must have user ids. We are talking of user authentication, not of user authorization. If you want to avoid user ids, you'll have to write you own "file system" authorization mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

No. SFTP works by logging in via SSH and then spawning the `sftpd` subprocess on the remote end.

You can, however, create a user that cannot log on *except* for sftp/scp by giving them the [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) program as a login shell. Fairly easy to do as long as you follow the steps, and about as secure as it gets.